# Over what protocol am I currently connected to a given server?

Tags: macos, network, server.app, smb, afp

At my workplace we usually connect to our server over AFP (I know it's been deprecated but the workers like to use the color labels). I sometimes use SMB to solve specific issues, including the inability to move/delete some files that lack AFP metadata, and just as a general "Let's try this instead" approach to solve problems.

To make sure we're connected over the protocol we want, we use the command-K interface and an address starting with afp:// or smb://. My question is this: Once a certain server appears in the Finder, regardless of how it got there (for example, from clicking a saved icon in the dock), is there a way to tell which protocol is being used to connect to it? This would help with troubleshooting, as when a coworker needs my help and doesn't want to disconnect from the server.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, on Mac OS X Leopard and higher, any connection discovered in the sidebar that connects via SMB will have the beige CRT with the Windows BSOD.

Any AFP connection will appear differently.